# update cell in a table won't get effected

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

Im trying to update one cell in my column,
in the debug mode, its going through the whole code, but it never get effected for some reason.  and not getting any errors.

this is my code :

```
else//wrong try!
{
    int errors;

    string gameHistory = Request.QueryString[0];
    errors = int.Parse(gameHistory);


    string query = "UPDATE HistoryOfGames SET NumberOfErrors=@NumberOfErrors WHERE ID='"+gameHistory+"'";
    con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=MICROSOF-58B8A5\\SQL_SERVER_R2;Initial Catalog=Daniel;Integrated Security=True");
    con.Open();
    string query2 = "SELECT NumberOfErrors FROM HistoryOfGames WHERE ID='"+gameHistory+"'";


    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query2, con);//checks how much errors was in the last time played.

    errors =(int)command.ExecuteScalar();

    command = new SqlCommand(query, con);

    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NumberOfErrors", errors);//set a new error.
    command.ExecuteNonQuery();

    con.Close();

}
```

thanks!

Comment: your sql query let met thnik your where clause is wrong. You are trying to compare a int field with a string value. In general, use only SqlParameter... for a lot of reason, especially to avoid parameter type wrong handling (but the main reason is security)

Comment: Usually ID fields need to be numeric, but in your case I see that it is a string. First off, I would check to see what the value is of your string variable gameHistory. If something is wrong there, consider giving your parameter a variable (VariableName in the code example) and then calling it as follows in your code: Request.QueryString["VariableName"];

Comment: You are updating the record with its old value previously selected, so no wonder that "never get effected for some reason". Maybe you want to increase it by 1 before you update it?!

Comment: but Im parsing the "error", isnt it saying that Im ok with it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like someone has been suggested, I've never changed "errors" integers, and didnt incresed it by one.

Thanks for all the helpers!

Answer (score 1):

Use SQL Server Profiler to check which query is executed on your server.

Answer (score 1):

i think your code is write but the sequence of statement is wrong.

please check this,

```
    command = new SqlCommand(query, con);     

    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NumberOfErrors", errors);//set a new error.     
    command.ExecuteNonQuery();     

    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query2, con);//checks how much errors was in the last time played.     

    errors =(int)command.ExecuteScalar();     
    con.Close();
```

first update errors then selet it.